# Returning Sequence From Function

Tags: clojure

I've put together the function below. It's supposed to take in a nested (multi-tiered) map and return a sequence of flat maps; however, it currently returns a sequence within a sequence.

Does anyone know why the sequence is being nested within another sequence?

```
(defn collapse [data & keys-coll]
  (if (map? data)
    (for [[k v] data]
      (collapse v (if (nil? keys-coll)
                    (conj [] k)
                    (conj (into [] keys-coll) k))))
    (hash-map (flatten keys-coll) data)))

(collapse {"a" {2011 [["a" 2011 "dan"] ["a" 2011 "ari"]] 2010 [["a" 2010 "jon"]]}})
```

Results in:

```
( ({("a" 2011) [["a" 2011 "dan"] ["a" 2011 "ari"]]}
   {("a" 2010) [["a" 2010 "jon"]]}) )
```

Expected/Desired result (notice the sequence, NOT a sequence within a sequence as above):

```
({("a" 2011) [["a" 2011 "dan"] ["a" 2011 "ari"]]}
 {("a" 2010) [["a" 2010 "jon"]]})
```

**Note**: The expected result is a sequence of maps; each map is comprised of composite keys and nested vectors.

Comment: The output sequence is nested because your input maps are nested. Can't really help you much further since I don't know what the code is *supposed* to do.

Comment: @JoostDiepenmaat: I've added more information about what the code is supposed to do. Essentially, the function is supposed to flatten a nested map into **a** sequence of flat maps. The function does flatten nested maps as desired but it returns a sequence of maps *within another sequence*, rather than just the sequence of maps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that you are getting a sequence within another sequence is that `for` returns a lazy seq. Because it is called every time `collapse` encounters a map and the map you provide nests two levels deep you're getting sequences nested two levels deep.

Quick fix: put a `flatten` in front of the `for` like so:

```
(defn collapse [data & keys-coll]
  (if (map? data)
    (flatten 
     (for [[k v] data]
       (collapse v (conj keys-coll k))))
    (hash-map (flatten keys-coll) data))
```

(Note that you can also get rid of the `if` statement). Maybe not the most elegant solution, but suffering from a brain freeze right now ...